# Can't access website using proxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, server, phantomjs

I set up PhantomJS to use it with Selenium for web scraping and I tried many proxy servers but every time I get redirected to some website with the title: Default Web Page. I don't know how to overcome this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time;

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36"
"(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36"
)
proxys = ['192.119.203.43:3128','89.249.207.65:3128','199.168.148.152:12345','96.31.64.186:80'];
phantomjs_path = "C:\Python27\misc\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows\phantomjs.exe"

service_args = [
'--proxy=96.31.64.186:80',
]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path,service_args=service_args, service_log_path=os.path.devnull, desired_capabilities=dcap)

browser.get("http://google.com")

browser.save_screenshot('testing.png');
print browser.title
```

Comment: Does it work if you would not set up the proxies? Do you see `Google` as a title?

Comment: yes it works, but as soon as I set up the proxy it gives that problem again

Comment: Is it reproducible with every proxy in the list? Also, if you set ur real browser to work through that proxy, can you open up the google page?

Comment: Yes, for example when I use a website like netscan that would let me visit internet pages using their proxy it works and it doesn't even detect the proxy but when I try to apply to my program this problem persists.

Comment: What if you omit the `80` port number? (since the default proxy type is http)

Comment: Also, are you sure these proxies don't require authentication? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if they require authentification, and when omitiing the 80 port number I get nothing.

Comment: it's alright now I just needed to find the right proxy ;)